# Русский язык и логика

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, лексическая-сочетаемость

Недавно прочитала такую историю. Позволю себе процитировать ее полностью.

> Тут говорят, русский язык логичнее. А попробуйте объяснить французу, почему
> стакан на столе стоит, вилка лежит, а птичка на дереве сидит.
> Со стаканом и вилкой я тут же вывела теорию: то, что скорее вертикальное, чем горизонтальное — оно стоит; то, что скорее горизонтальное, чем вертикальное — оно лежит. Моя теория тут же разбилась о тарелку — она скорее горизонтальная, чем вертикальная, но стоит. Хотя если её перевернуть, то будет лежать. Тут же на ходу выводится еще одна теория: тарелка стоит, потому что у неё есть основание, она стоит на основании. Теория немедленно разбивается в хлам о сковородку – у нее нет основания, но она всё равно стоит. Чудеса. Хотя если её засунуть в мойку, то там она будет лежать, приняв при этом положение более вертикальное, чем на столе. Отсюда напрашивается вывод, что всё, что готово к использованию, стоит. (На этом месте хочется сказать пошлость.)
> Но вот возьмём еще один предмет — мяч обыкновенный детский. Он не горизонтальный и не вертикальный, при этом полностью готов к использованию. Кто же скажет, что там, в углу, мяч стоит? Если мяч не выполняет роль куклы и его не наказали, то он всё-таки лежит. И даже если его перенести на стол, то и на столе (о чудо!) он будет лежать. Усложним задачу — положим мяч в тарелку, а тарелку в сковородку. Теперь у нас мяч по-прежнему лежит (в тарелке), сковородка по-прежнему стоит (на столе), вопрос, что делает тарелка?
> Если француз дослушал объяснение до конца, то всё, его мир уже никогда не будет прежним. В нём появились тарелки и сковородки, которые умеют стоять и лежать — мир ожил. Осталось добавить, что птички у нас сидят. На ветке, на подоконнике и даже на тротуаре. Француз нарисует в своем воображении синицу, сидящую на ветке на пятой точке и болтающую в воздухе лапками, или бомжующую ворону, сидящую, вытянув лапы и растопырив крылья, у станции метро. «Русские — вы сумасшедшие!» — скажет француз и закинет в вас учебником.

Кто-то может внести ясность в этот спор? По какой логике предмет лежит или стоит?

Р. М. (после правки): вполне возможно, что текст взят [отсюда](https://entre-2-mondes.livejournal.com/77158.html) (03.12. 2011).

Answer (score 10):

Есть старый анекдот. Как русские различают зайца и зайчиху. 
Если побежал - значит, заяц. А если побежала - зайчиха. 
Вот тут тот же случай. Если вы предмет положили - он лежит. А если поставили - то стоит.

Вы интересный вопрос задали, но герой истории совершенно негодными методами его решить пытался.
Сначала методические ошибки. Во-первых, сравнение с другими языками заведомо ничего не даст. Во-вторых, в языке нет и не может быть абсолютных правил, единых на все случаи. Есть некоторая статистика, более и менее продуктивные шаблоны. Язык - не математика, один контрпример не должен опровергать всю теорию. Сковородки и мячи вас не должны были бы смущать. Разумеется, если теория верная.

И самое главное. За внешней формой он совершенно забыл про функциональность. А она здесь главная.
Начнём с "сидеть". Птицы - особенно на ветках - именно сидят, с поджатыми лапками, опущенными хвостами... Стоять могут только бегающие или ходящие птицы - и только на земле. Ну или там на болоте. Другие случаи "сидения", не птичьего, определяются соответствующими значениями глагола "сидеть", я здесь их опускаю.
Разница же между "лежать" и "стоять" не такая уж абсолютная. Та же сковородка может стоять на плите и лежать (да ещё вверх дном) в кладовке. Важно, что у неё нет двух "рабочих" положений, строго различающихся "вертикальностью-горизонтальностью".

Так что в тех случаях, когда у предмета не два очевидных положения (лыжи, там, лестница или веник) разница между стоянием и лежанием может определяться функциональностью (стоит на плите - лежит в кладовке). С круглыми предметами (мяч, клубок) ещё проще. "Стоять" (т. е. находиться в теоретически неподвижном состоянии) они могут только на специальной подставке. Иначе они лежат. В ямке, сумке или просто на полу.
Других принципиальных случаев я не вижу. Но если появятся, думаю, их тоже можно будет объяснить.

Answer (score 6):

В каждом языке формируется своя *логика* (выражаясь словами автора вопроса, **Amarie**). Иногда эта логика идёт с **незапамятных** времён, в самом буквальном смысле этого слова. Уже никто не помнит, почему именно так говорится. Может быть влияние какого-то соседнего языка, а может быть влияние какого-то давно забытого и исчезнувшего языка. На вопрос "почему" вам скорее всего ответят -- так говорится, так надо и всё.

На окраинах географического распространения русского языка с этим "стоять/лежать" могут быть свои вариации. Плюс ещё "класть/ложить". Я как-то общался с одной девушкой с Западной Украины (умницей и красавицей; не похожей на тот стереотип, что по ТВ любят показывать). Так она говорила, что на столе у нас всё стоит! :-) Если Центр и Восток Украины слова "стоять/лежать" употребляет аналогично россиянам, то на Западе Украины свои особенности.

А вот хорошее видео для поднятия настроения форумчанам.

[X-Factor Одесса: Катерина Пуйческу | youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=CdnP7iibpvI)

Вспомнил в связи с этой темой. Это отрывок из укр. конкурса "Х-фактор". Там член жюри, рэпер Серёга, спрашивает участницу конкурса, молдаванку... Подробнее в видео с 2:10 до 2:35. :-)

По-украински в этом видео говорят мало и ничего важного (в основном, 1-ая минута видео, о том как участница готовится-волнуется; вообще можно пропустить). Спела молдаванка хорошо, можно послушать, но к теме обсуждения это отношения не имеет.

Comment: Nikolja, а с какой минуты настроение должно подниматься? У меня хватило терпения до 1:47

Comment: >Там на 2-ой минуте член жюри, рэпер Серёга, спрашивает участницу конкурса, молдаванку...

Прошу прощения, писал на скорую руку и допустил неточность. "На 2-ой минуте" это же промежуток времени между 1-ой и 2-ой минутами? Исправлю в своём тексте. 

Пример по теме между 2:10 и 2:35. Дальше -- весёлая зажигательная молдавская песня. К теме обсуждения отношения не имеет, смотреть по желанию.

Answer (score 5):

Марк Твен как-то дал в газете лаконичную заметку: «Слухи о моей смерти сильно преувеличены». К чему я это? А к тому, что названная нелогичность, даже абсурдность нашего языка — мнимая. Как человек, владеющий английским, могу вас заверить: у англичан птички тоже сидят, стаканы, дома и тарелки стоят, вилки, подушки и газеты лежат и т. д. Кое в чём английский более логичен (скажем, камень у них вроде бы только стоит, но не лежит — поправьте, если ошибаюсь). Но зато наш язык логичнее в других аспектах. Во французском я слаб, но схожие закавыки с сидением, лежанием и стояниьем у них вроде бы тоже наличествуют. Подытоживая, замечу, что языковая логика не обязана быть проста и прямолинейна.

Кстати, история написана дивно. Живо, ярко, красочно, с юмором.

Comment: Но Вы так и не ответили на вопрос: по какой логике в русском языке предмет стоит или лежит?

Answer (score 0):

В России, как известно, лень - весьма уважаемое и распространенное качество, поэтому состояния, окрашенные этакой "ленивой модальностью", в языке отличаются от прочих. Тарелка лежит, если она отдыхает, и стоит, если работает или готова к работе (на столе). Даже автомобиль в гараже стоит (готов к поездке), а на свалке скорее лежит (отдыхает). Мяч почти всегда пассивен, этакий несчастный увалень, которого вечно пинают, поэтому он почти всегда лежит. Тарелка в сковородке - пограничная ситуация, но все же скорее лежит, ибо не функционирует и не готова к этому. Не будет ошибкой сказать "лестница лежит в сарае", даже если фактически она там стоит вертикально. В сарае лестница отдыхает.

Если мяч или камень *стоят* на подставке - такое времяпровождение превращается для них из отдыха (увы) в работу.

Итак, ленивые - лежат, работяги - стоят. Вероятно, "стояние" изначально только вертикальных предметов было обобщено на всех работяг. Так уж вышло.

Comment: Вы название прочитали вопроса? **Русский язык и логика**. Вот с последним у вас что-то плохо. Про чем тут ленивые работяги, если один и тот же предмет может и стоять, и лежать? Да еще и сидеть при этом? Не скажем, на гайка на резьбе?

Comment: @behemothus Лень - это не клеймо на всю жизнь, а состояние души. Оно может покинуть"один и тот же предмет", а затем вернуться обратно. Вероятно, вы никогда не испытывали этого прекрасного чувства возвращения... сочувствую..:)

Comment: @behemothus В сущности, я лишь развил ваше замечание про "функциональность", хотя старался избежать этого неуклюжего и слишком общего слова, в современном языке чрезмерно перегруженного (кстати, примененного вами не совсем точно: не функциональность, а скорее состояние функционирования/нефункционирования, это разные понятия, функциональность тарелки как раз неизменна, алаверды, между прочим, насчет логики ;). Другими словами, "стоит" функционирующий или готовый к функционированию предмет, "лежит" не функционирующий и не готовый.

Comment: А не надо ничего "развивать". Здесь ценятся законченные и логичные ответы. У вас нет ни того, ни другого. О чем я Вам и сообщил. Дискуссии "по порядку ведения" тоже не приветствуются.

Answer (score 0):

Такое же положение происходит и с "в\на".
"Работаю на дому" (по логике звучит, как сверху дома).
"Я поеду на автобусе\на самолёте\на машине". Предполагаю, что в старину в транспорт нельзя было помещаться внутрь - тележка, повозка, лошадь т.п. Так и повелось. Но, странно ведь в старину говорили: "Поеду в карете\повезу тебя в золотой карете" (что означала правильную логику, поместиться внутрь транспорта и ехать), но почему-то это понятие не прижилось в современном русском языке.

Comment: Не-не, с "домом" такая логика не пройдет. Это особенное существительное: у него есть местный падеж (где?).  Сверху — на доме; внутри — в доме (в дому́, разг.); работаю на дому́ = работаю до́ма. (http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC) P.S. Давненько Вас не было. Приветствую.