# Как правильно говорить: "тарелка стоит на столе" или "лежит на столе"?

Tags: лингвистика

Тарелка стоит или лежит на столе?

Comment: Был такой вопрос. Наберите в справке - стоит или лежит.

Answer (score 1):

Если тарелка находится в штатном положении (дном вниз) - то "стоит".

Если тарелка находится на боку (прислонена к чему-то или находится в специальной стойке) - то тоже "стоит".

Если тарелка находится в любом другом положении (например - дном вверх) - то "лежит".

Answer (score 0):

Об этом подробно писали [вот тут](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/1521/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)