# В сковороде или на сковороде?

Tags: лексика

Рассуждения о блинах натолкнули меня на вопрос: а как же все-таки правильно — "в сковороде" или "на сковороде"? И, если "на", то почему тогда "в кастрюле"? Только ли из-за формы и высоты бортиков посуды?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Было где-то что-то подобное, насчет нелогичности языка, сейчас найду.
Вот [оно](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/1521/%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Конкретно по вопросу насчет высоты бортиков: думаю, да. Только дело не напрямую в бортиках , а в рабочей поверхности. Если боковые поверхности существенны для термического процесса, то - В. Если играют вспомогательную роль, то НА. Таким образом в принципе по отношению к одной и той же посуде можно употреблять и В и НА. В зависимости от технологии. Сковорода - один их таких предметов. Но обычно всё-таки используют посуду, приспособленную под конкретный процесс. Поэтому жарят обычно - на сковороде, а тушат - в сковороде. И сковородки при этом разной формы.