# Как объяснить иностранцу выбор глаголов лежит-сидит-стоит

Tags: лексика, семантика

Приятель (не филолог) предложил сформулировать правило для иностранца, когда употреблять глагол **стоит**, когда - **сидит**, а когда - **лежит**. Я попыталась, но чётких правил у меня так и не получилось составить. Может, у кого-то получится?

*Стакан на столе стоит, а вилка лежит. Если мы воткнем вилку в столешницу, вилка будет стоять.* 
То есть стоят вертикальные предметы, а лежат горизонтальные?
*Добавляем на стол тарелку и сковороду. Они вроде как горизонтальные, но на столе стоят.* 
*Теперь положим тарелку в сковородку. Там она лежит, а ведь на столе стояла.* 
Может быть, стоят предметы готовые к использованию? Нет, вилка-то готова была, когда лежала. *Теперь на стол залезает кошка. Она может стоять, сидеть и лежать.* Если в плане стояния и лежания она как-то лезет в логику «вертикальный-горизонтальный», то сидение — это новое свойство. Сидит она на попе. *Теперь на стол села птичка. Она на столе сидит, но сидит на ногах, а не на попе.* Хотя вроде бы должна стоять. Но стоять она не может вовсе. *Однако если мы убьём бедную птичку и сделаем чучело, оно будет на столе стоять.* Может показаться, что сидение — атрибут живого, но *сапог на ноге тоже сидит, хотя он не живой и не имеет попы.*

**Так что же стоит, что лежит, а что сидит?**

Comment: Мне кажется, что подобный вопрос уже был. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/1521/Русский-язык-и-логика

Comment: Да, действительно, видимо, оттуда и пошла история, я просто пропустила. Но ведь окончательного ответа-то, всеми принятого,  нет. Похожую логику пыталась использовать - отвергла. Вот сапог-то почему сидит? Видимо, есть другие подходы. может, кто-то найдёт что-то новенькое?

Answer (score 5):

А мне выбор ***стоит – лежит – сидит*** в русском языке **кажется вполне логичным.**

**Стоят все предметы, в которых можно различить  низ (основание) и верхнюю часть.**  Поэтому   тарелки, чашки, кастрюли на столе стоят, так как именно в таком положении они выполняют свои функции. А вот ложки и вилки этого качества лишены, поэтому на столе (и во всех других местах) они лежат.

**Если тарелку поместить в раковину,** то она будет там лежать весте с ложками и вилками, так как ее функциональное положение  уже не важно.

**Мяч** круглый, низа и верха не имеет и поэтому всегда лежит.

**Человек**, как известно, может занимать оба положения (лежать и стоять), да к тому же еще способен сидеть. **К другим живым существам**  эти названия применяются по  возможности: кошка сидит, лежит и стоит, корова лежит и стоит.

**А почему птичка** сидит (на ветке, на крыше)? Это **условное** название, так как у живой птички только одна неподвижная поза.

**Костюм** может "хорошо сидеть", а также висеть в шкафу или лежать на плоской поверхности (это все его возможности).

Я думаю, что иностранец должен понять такие объяснения.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Еще о слове "сидеть"

Вот так  в словаре описывается **поза**:

СИДЕТЬ,1. Находиться в вертикальном положении, при котором туловище опирается на что-л. своей нижней частью, а ноги (лапы) согнуты или вытянуты;

А это **переносное значение:**

Находиться на какой-л. поверхности, не двигаясь, не перемещаясь (о насекомых, птицах). Мухи сидят на потолке. На щеке сидит комар.

Располагаться на поверхности или внутри каким-л. образом (о частях тела, одежде и т.п.). Глаза сидят глубоко. Гвоздь крепко сидит. Пробка сидит плотно. Костюм сидит безукоризненно. Пиджак сидит мешком (о болтающемся не по фигуре пиджаке). Тральщик мелко сидит (мор.; имеет такую осадку).

**Перенос значения основан на сходстве.**

Когда белка (или птица) сидит на дереве, то ее ножек не видно, кажется, что она действительно сидит, опираясь туловищем. Овощи сидят на грядке, но сам корнеплод мы не видим, он находится под землей. Также у сидящего в стене гвоздя видна только шляпка.

Comment: Не все случаи охвачены. Рассмотрим плоские предметы, не имеющие выраженного верха и низа. Когда доска стоит/лежит?

Comment: Я уж не говорю о переносном значении. Тишина может и стоять, и лежать. Туман стоит/лежит.

Comment: А в перевернутом виде? Человек стоит на голове, а тарелка?

Comment: А в посудомоечной машине тарелка стоит на боку, а человек на боку лежит (в кровати).

Comment: Ну, вертикальное или горизонтальное расположение, безусловно, надо учитывать. Доски стоят в углу, если их поставить, прислонив к стене, или  лежат, если их положить. Тут также прослеживается связь с глаголами ставить и класть. То же с туманом,  только он сам   занимает вертикальное положение (стоит стеной)  или горизонтальное положение (лежит, стелется по земле).  И все остальные примеры тоже.

Comment: А Вы хотели бы найти общую идею для различения двух положений  для множества возможных вариантов? Или, возможно, у Вас уже есть такая идея? Пока представлены две идеи: обозначенный верх и низ и вертикаль-горизонталь.

Comment: Выбор глагола вторичен (если будет стоять, то поставим, а будет лежать — положим). Тот же туман может восприниматься по разному, как стена или как толстый слой, но может стоять как погода (быть).

Comment: Подведем итог. Есть два основных положения (стоит - лежит), Есть факторы, склоняющие нас к одному из двух решений. Вы определяете эти факторы в каждом конкретном случае и делаете выбор. Ситуаций множество, но выбрать можно только одно слово из двух возможных.

Answer (score 0):

Это очень хороший вопрос! Но он является "коаном".
Что это такое, я сейчас объясню.
 Коан - вопрос, не имеющий логического ответа.  Например: "Что было раньше: яйцо или курица?"
Либо:
" - Где находится вселенная? 
- В сознании. 
- А где находится сознание?"
  Подобные вопросы, либо диалоги применяются в буддийских практиках для достижения просветленности сознания. Человеку необходимо отказаться от привычного логического мышления, а когда ему это удаётся, - все вопросы исчезают навсегда.
  Так вот, для того, чтобы иностранец мог понять алогичные, на первый взгляд, моменты русского языка, он должен отказаться от привычного мышления, свойственного носителям его языка, и начать мыслить как русский.
  Вы спросили о правиле, вот оно: иностранец должен стать русским.

Comment: Ну почему же? Не такое уж алогичное мышление у русских. просто, я думаю, мы теряем эту логику, когда забываем исконное значение слов. Иногда нужно покопаться в истории слов. Многозначность основана на многих явлениях языка, пока я этого в ответах не увидела, кроме логики горизонтальное/вертикальное, но эта логика не все значения объясняет.